# "chained" spherical coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinates

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how to solve my problem. I have tried searching online but i'm not sure i'm using the correct terminology.

In essence my problem is this.
I have three spheres, let's call them A, B and C. I am calculating the controlling the position of sphere B by adjusting my theta, phi and R using sphere A's position as the origin. The position of sphere C is being controlled like sphere B, i am adjusting my theta, phi and R using sphere B's position as the origin.

The three spheres start in a line with the spacing controlled by the respective R values (shown in picture 1).
[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykUoI.png)

As i raise sphere B by adjusting it's coordinates sphere C moves with it but remains level with sphere B (picture 2)
[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmL8l.png)

but i need it to appear like (picture 3).
[picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJaPO.png)

My understanding of the problem is that the 'reference frame' (not sure i'm using the correct term here) has my inclination axis as 'flat' (picture 2) but i would need to be rotated (picture 3) in order for an inclination angle of zero to position the sphere how i need it

**Update:
I found this, but i'm not sure this would solve my issue:
[Vector transform: Spherical coordinates in one frame to another, staying in spherical](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2015343/vector-transform-spherical-coordinates-in-one-frame-to-another-staying-in-sphe)